# Python Pandas: Split-apply-combine, error in variable length when function is applied to second group?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe, split-apply-combine

I'm noticing some bizarre behavior when trying to make use of the Split-Apply-Combine paradigm in Python Pandas - Variable `x` will not take the correct length!

**An overview of what I am trying to accomplish:**

1. Split a dataframe containing data for multiple companies using the groupby() operation into groups (one for each company)
2. Calculate the information surplus for each group
3. Return a new dataframe with results

For the first group, the calculation is perfect! However, on the second group, it seems to inherit the length of the previous variable when slicing the dataframe - Why is this? As you can see from the code and provided debug, I've attempted to identify the issue but can't see it, any help would be appreciated!

**The function call:**

```
data_nasdaq_top_100_preprocessed_mi_res = sentisignal.split_apply_combine(data_nasdaq_top_100_preprocessed_merge, 'SYMBOL', sentisignal.information_surplus, 10, 'PCA_SENTIMENT', 'PCA_FINANCE', -1, True)
```

**The debug (and issue):**

First group:

```
['AAL'] exante  True
len(df.index) 928
shift_x length 928
len(x.index) 927 len(x) 927 end_index 927
len(x) 927
doane 927
success
```

Second group:

```
['AAPL'] exante  True
len(df.index) 1006
shift_x length 1006
len(x.index) 78 len(x) 78 end_index 1005
len(x) 78
doane 78
success
```

This is the issue - For some reason the length of `x` is reduced to 78 (it should be 1005!), mysteriously 1006 - 928 = 78 (length of first group - length of second group)

**The code:**

Split apply combine method

```
def split_apply_combine(df, key, func, *args):
# print "args:", args
return df.groupby(key).apply(func, *args)
```

Information surplus method (with debug)

```
def information_surplus(df, time_shift, varx, vary, bins, exante):
print df.SYMBOL.unique(), "exante ", exante

output = []

if exante:
    shift_range = range(0, -(time_shift+1), -1)
else:
    shift_range = range(0, time_shift+1)

print "len(df.index)", len(df.index)

for i in shift_range:
    if abs(i) > len(df.index):
        break

    shift_x = df[varx].shift(i)
    print "shift_x length", len(shift_x)

    if exante:
        end_index = (len(shift_x.index) - 1 - abs(i))
        x = shift_x.ix[1:end_index]
        y = df[vary].ix[1:end_index]
        print "len(x.index)", len(x.index), "len(x)", len(x), "end_index", end_index
    else:
        print "exec"
        x = shift_x.ix[1+abs(i):]
        y = df[vary].ix[1+abs(i):]

    mi = calc_mutual_information(x, y, bins)

    if i == 0:
        mi_origin = mi

    if mi_origin == 0: 
        inf_surp_pct = 0
    else:
        inf_surp_pct = (mi - mi_origin) / mi_origin * 100

    output.append({'SHIFT': i, 'MUTUAL_INFORMATION': mi, 'INFORMATION_SURPLUS_DIFF': mi - mi_origin, 'INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT': inf_surp_pct})

output_frame = pd.DataFrame(output)
return output_frame
```

Mutual information method

```
def calc_mutual_information(x, y, bins):
print "len(x)", len(x)

try:
    if bins == -1:
        bins = doane_bin(x)
    if bins == np.inf:
        bins = sturges_bin(x)
except ValueError:
    bins = 10.0
# print "bins", bins
try:
    c_xy = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins)[0]
    mi = metrics.mutual_info_score(None, None, contingency=c_xy)
    print "success"
except Exception,e: 
    print "error with mi calc", str(e)
    mi = 0
return mi
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

Updating the information surplus to be used without `.ix`, I've updated the question title to try and reflect this and will happy accept an answer with an explanation!

The updated method:

```
def information_surplus(df, time_shift, varx, vary, bins, exante):
print df.SYMBOL.unique(), "exante ", exante

output = []

if exante:
    shift_range = range(0, -(time_shift+1), -1)
else:
    shift_range = range(0, time_shift+1)

# print "len(df.index)", len(df.index)

for i in shift_range:
    if abs(i) > len(df.index):
        break

    shift_x = df[varx].shift(i)
    # print "shift_x length", len(shift_x)

    mi = 0.0

    if exante:
        end_index = (len(shift_x.index) - 1 - abs(i))
        x = shift_x[1:end_index]
        y = df[vary][1:end_index]
        # print "len(x.index)", len(x.index), "len(x)", len(x), "end_index", end_index
    else:
        # print "exec"
        x = shift_x.ix[1+abs(i):]
        y = df[vary].ix[1+abs(i):]

    mi = calc_mutual_information(x, y, bins)

    if i == 0:
        mi_origin = mi

    if mi_origin == 0: 
        inf_surp_pct = 0
    else:
        inf_surp_pct = (mi - mi_origin) / mi_origin * 100

    output.append({'SHIFT': i, 'MUTUAL_INFORMATION': mi, 'INFORMATION_SURPLUS_DIFF': mi - mi_origin, 'INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT': inf_surp_pct})

output_frame = pd.DataFrame(output)
return output_frame
```